# Scala: From string to tuple

Tags: scala, tuples

I am very naive in programming as well as in scala. 
I have a file with following content:

```
football type game
John comment "football is the best game"
```

I want to make it tuple like this

```
(football, type, game)
(John, comment, "football is the best game")
```

Could somebody tell me how can I do that in scala.

Comment: What have you tried?  Show your code attempts and we can help correct any misconceptions.

Comment: fileLines.map { line =>      {
        val lineSplit = line.split(" ")
         (lineSplit(0), lineSplit(1), lineSplit(2))
        }
   }
But the problem with 3rd field of tuple.

Comment: Instead of just using the third element from the array, just concatenate everything after the first two elements, and use that as the third field of the tuple

Comment: So, does this file have more lines besides these 2? Can we have quoted elements anywhere or just in the third position? Can there be quotes inside quotes?

Comment: This file has thousands of lines but the structure is similar. Quoted elements are in the third position only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague.  If the multi-word string is limited to 3rd element of the tuple, it can be accomplished like so:

```
fileLines.map { line =>
  val lineSplit = line.split(" ")
  (lineSplit(0), lineSplit(1), lineSplit.drop(2).mkString(" "))
}
```

But if the quote-delimited string can happen for any of the three tuple members then you've got a lot more processing involved.  I think I'd be tempted to split the entire string and then do a search for any elements with a single quote mark and then try to match them.  Not trivial.